# Connection refused: Operation Timed out in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos

Ever since upgrading my Mac OS to Mohave, I have been having issues running my rails server locally at my home network. The reason I say home network is because it works just fine when I'm connected on the network at my office. When I run `rails s` and to go localhost:3000, I see the logs working and running queries to get data from my PG database, until it ultimately stops and times out with the following error:

```
[2019-01-02T20:13:21.417980 #65251]  INFO -- : method=GET path=/ format=html controller=DashboardController action=index status=500 error='ActionView::Template::Error: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "172.18.8.52" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried reinstalling PG with brew, I also tried changing the ports. I checked my firewall and nothing is blocking 5432 port. And oddly enough, I can connect to PG using my PSequel GUI through localhost at port 5432.

The next thing that caught my attention is the IP address listed in the error message. I don't recognize it. After doing `nslookup 172.18.8.52` I get:

```
nslookup 172.18.8.52
Server:     2001:558:feed::1
Address:    2001:558:feed::1#53

** server can't find 52.8.18.172.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? This is driving me nuts!

I'm running Rails 5.1.4.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was an issue with the ssh tunneling.